# Vue directive after v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a set of data I pull in via Firebase. I want to display the images referenced in the Firebase data in a carousel. I have setup a directive (below) The issue I'm having is with the `v-for`. The directive runs prior to `v-for` and thus, no carousel as the items do not exist.

Directive:

```
  directives: {
    slick: {
      inserted: function (el) {
        $(el).slick({
          arrows: false,
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 4000,
          speed: 2000,
          fade: true,
          pauseOnHover: false
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<div v-slick>
  <div v-for="sponsor in sponsors">
    {{sponsor.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait to instantiate the directive until `sponsors` contains data.

One quick and dirty way to do this:

```
<div v-slick v-if="sponsors.length"> ... </div>
```